# Fundamental doubt about partial differentiation: Sum of derivates equals derivate of the sum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $z$ be a function of $x$ and $y$: $z=f(x,y)$.

$ z=x^2+ y^2$. Now, if you take $\frac{\partial z}{\partial z}$ we can agree this is equal to 1. But what if we wanted to take each derivate separately, that is: $ \frac{\partial x^2}{\partial z} 
+ \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial z} $ ?

Are you allowed to reason this way? If so, how would you compute the result?

Comment: Apply the chain rule: $\frac{d[x^2]}{dz} = \frac{dx}{dz} \cdot \frac{d[x^2]}{dx}$

Comment: @ Dstarred How would you calculate $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$ ?

Comment: Unless you parametricize, you cannot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do so, you need to express $x$ and $y$ in function of $z$. In the present case, those variables lie on a circle of radius $\sqrt{z}$ with the following parametrization :
$$
\begin{cases}
   x = \sqrt{z}\cos\theta \\
   y = \sqrt{z}\sin\theta
\end{cases}
$$
where $\theta$ is a free parameter, hence
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(x^2+y^2) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(z\cos^2\theta+z\sin^2\theta) = \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta = 1
$$

**N.B. :** that's an abstract circle, (not a real one on $\mathbb{R}^2$), so that it works even if $z\not\in\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: Wow, very clever movement. But is there any specific  why you must do that? Lets say, if I where to take $\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial z} $ and write it as $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}  .\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial x} $ Do you have any idea how i would procede?

Comment: @Qxap   Not really, but $x$, $y$ and $z$ are linked/related by the equation/constraint, so that the dependence of $x,y$ on $z$ should be deduced from this relation.

Comment: @Qxap - your fundamental problem is that partial differentials, in their present notation, do not contain enough information in and of themselves to be manipulated in the algebraic sense you are trying to do here.  To see the problems and notational solutions, see the paper "Total and Partial Differentials as Algebraically Manipulable Entities". https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.07958